# Custom query methods on SpringData CrudRepository picked up as bean property

Tags: spring-data

I'm trying to add some custom query methods to a CrudRepository. I followed the example in the spring-data-examples repo for jpa/example/.../custom. It defines the repo interface like:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom {
```

In my equivalent of UserRepositoryCustom I have my custom methods, and I have another class that implements these. There's so much magic I've no idea how SpringData is finding these classes! In my implementation I have a custom query method called createUserGroup(). When I attempt to run tests, I get..

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property createUserGroup found for type User!

How do I tell SpringData about my custom implementation so that it doesn't attempt to interpret the custom interface methods as magic query-by-method-name methods?

Answer (score 0):

Ah - it seems the magic is looking for a class that implements the interface with the same name and 'Impl' appended to it. The documentation makes no mention of this. I only figured it out from a badly written comment in the example.

Convention over configuration sucks if you don't happen to know the convention.